# Nested JSON as an input to/Output from REST API's using Azure AD B2C Custom Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to send a request in a nested JSON format as below to REST Service using Azure AD B2C Policy customisation

Claim:
"signInNames":
 [
        {
            "type": "emailAddress",
            "value": "abc@test.com"
        }
]

The technical profile for REST Call looks something like this:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="RestCall">
     <DisplayName>Nested JSON Claim to REST</DisplayName>
     <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
     <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://<<REST API CALL>></Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
     </Metadata>
     <InputClaims>
     <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames"/>
     </InputClaims>
     </TechnicalProfile>
```

I want to send the value part of the signInNames while sending an input to rest service
Also, I want to fetch the value part when received as response from a REST Service.

I referred the following stack overflow question but it is unanswered:
[Json type claim in Azure AD B2C custom policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162534/json-type-claim-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Custom claims are currently in public preview.

I suggest you visit the [advanced policy claims documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%206.md) in the Azure Samples Github repository. You can also try [adding optional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) in JSON form to the Manifest section.

Comment: This link shared above is not working.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%206.md